# Pygame get if any key has changed

Tags: python, pygame

Is it possible to get the change states of every key from pygame.key.get_pressed()? i.e. set a key to 1 if it is up but was down, or is down but was up, otherwise 0.

My thoughts were to have something like the following code, but that doesn't work because pygame.key.get_pressed() isn't an iterable.

```
last_pressed = pressed
pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
changed = {key: pressed[key] != last_pressed[key] for key in pressed}
```

I intend on using this to toggle several features, and would rather a consise method for readablility.

Comment: My current workaround is to have a monitor list containing all the nescecary keys, but I'm still curious if there's a better way to live.

Comment: use event KEYDOWN, KEYUP to get which key changed state.

Comment: do you get error ? always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot).

Comment: And show your current method

Comment: Could you add more background information? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Maybe there's a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`get_pressed()` gives list, not dictionary so `for key in pressed` gives values from this list which can be `0` or `1` (`False` or `True`)

To get only key's numbers which changed state you can use

```
changed = [idx for idx in range(len(pressed)) if pressed[idx] != last_pressed[idx]]
```

or using `zip()` and `enumerate()`

```
changed = [idx for idx, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(last_pressed, pressed)) if a != b]
```

Full code

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 200))

pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
is_running = True

while is_running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            is_running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                is_running = False

    last_pressed = pressed
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    changed = [idx for idx in range(len(pressed)) if pressed[idx] != last_pressed[idx]]
    # or
    changed = [idx for idx, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(last_pressed, pressed)) if a != b]

    print(changed)

    clock.tick(25)

pygame.quit()
```

---

The same with `KEYDOWN` and `KEYUP`

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 200))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
is_running = True

while is_running:

    changed = []

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            is_running = False
        elif event.type in (pygame.KEYDOWN, pygame.KEYUP):
            changed.append(event.key)

    print(changed)

    clock.tick(25)

pygame.quit()
```

---

To get `True/False` for all keys:

```
changed = [pressed[idx] != last_pressed[idx] for idx in range(len(pressed))]
```

or using `zip()`

```
changed = [a != b for a, b in zip(last_pressed, pressed)]
```

Comment: Ah, so it is iterable, but I'm a doofus in thinking it was some sort of internal data type. Do you happen to know if the keys are the same in every OS and system?

Comment: PyGame has [variables like pygame.K_a](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) to work with keys and they rather should be the same.